# How to use lipo to strip simulator binaries from an xcframework?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, lipo

I have a 3rd party fat xcframework and wish to strip the emulator portion from it.

I used lipo on a .framework several years ago, however this time it's a .xcframework I am using.

This command used to work with a .framework:

lipo -info NameOfFramework.xcframework

However with the .xcframework it give the error:

fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't map input file: NameOfFramework.xcframework (Invalid argument)

Comment: You can open the .xcframework folder and delete the folder ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator and then open the Info.plist(in the .xcframework folder) and remove from the array the <dict></dict> entry with the LibraryIdentifier ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator